# Laravel Login and redirect depending on role id

Tags: laravel, authentication

So I have login page that the admin or users can use to login. It went well until such time we have some changes and added the admin side. I only uses 1 table for all user types and I have `role_id` column that defines the users role. So if the `role_id` is `0`, I have to redirect them to the dashboard page whereas if it's a user, will redirect to user page. I have tried as what is suggested in the internet but can't make it work. Here's what I have:

```
class UserLoginController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest:user')->except('logout');
    }

    public function showLoginForm()
    {
        return view('auth.user-login');
    }

    public function login(UserLoginRequest $request)
    {
        // Attempt to log the user in
        if (Auth::guard('user')->attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password])) {
            // if successful, then redirect to their intended location
            return redirect()->intended(route('user.dashboard'));
        }

        // if unsuccessful, then redirect back to the login with the form data
        if (! User::where('email', $request->email)->where('password', bcrypt($request->password))->first() ) {
            return redirect()->back()
                ->withInput($request->only('email'))
                ->withErrors(['status' =>  'Incorrect username or password.']);
        }
    }
    public function logout()
    {
        Auth::guard('user')->logout();
        return redirect()->route('user.login');
    }
}
```

**config/auth**

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'users',
        'hash' => false,
    ],

    'guest' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'guests',
    ],

    'user' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
],

'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,
    ],

    'guests' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Guest::class,
    ],

],
```

**MODEL**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    protected $guard = 'user';

    protected $fillable = [
        //fillable cols
    ];

    //change role id data type to integer
    protected $casts = [
        'role_id' => 'integer',
    ];
}
```

Now, where should I insert the condition to check if it's an admin or a user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try it

```
public function login(UserLoginRequest $request)
    {
        // Attempt to log the user in
        if (!Auth::guard('user')->attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password])) {
            return redirect()->back()
                ->withInput($request->only('email'))
                ->withErrors(['status' =>  'Incorrect username or password.']);
        }

        $user = Auth::guard('user')->user();
        if ($user->role_id === 0) {
            return redirect()->route('user.dashboard');
        }
        return redirect()->route('user.page'); 
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not working, it redirects all user to user page.

Comment: could you show me the type of  ```role_id``` column in your database?

Comment: Okay. Thanks for that one, I will be testing this several times. I'm using string in db, now change to int. Will accept this one if it will pass other tests.

Comment: If you don't want to change database type, you can use attribute casting in eloquent. In the User model, add it ``` protected $casts = ['role_id' => 'integer'];```

Comment: I have tried casting it in my model but it still doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

Check below i have edited the method of login:

```
public function login(UserLoginRequest $request)
    {
        // Attempt to log the user in
        if (Auth::guard('user')->attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password])) {
        // Over here this condition will be true when user is successfully login 
       // Below is the user data i have printed in that you can check the role of user which is login.
         $user = Auth::user();
          print_r($user);

        }

        // if unsuccessful, then redirect back to the login with the form data
        if (! User::where('email', $request->email)->where('password', bcrypt($request->password))->first() ) {
            return redirect()->back()
                ->withInput($request->only('email'))
                ->withErrors(['status' =>  'Incorrect username or password.']);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have already tried this one and it has `Trying to get property 'role_id' of non-object`

Comment: Please write print_r(Auth::user()); and check role_id field you are getting or not.If it is getting then in which form data is getting.

Comment: It's displaying `null`.

Comment: then in your providers also, maybe you missed it there also. below that guards.

Comment: @Qonvex620 Updated.